# Python with Google Analytics Querying a specific Google Account from Googles scripts

Tags: python, api, google-analytics, analytics

I am quite new to Python and got the following script from Google Analytics API help. I have got it working and extracting data, however, it specifies to get the first google account, I have multiple GA accounts and wish to specify just one. Any help would be great?

Thanks

Craig

```
"""A simple example of how to access the Google Analytics API."""

import argparse

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

import httplib2
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import file
from oauth2client import tools



def get_service(api_name, api_version, scope, key_file_location,
                service_account_email):
  """Get a service that communicates to a Google API.

  Args:
    api_name: The name of the api to connect to.
    api_version: The api version to connect to.
    scope: A list auth scopes to authorize for the application.
    key_file_location: The path to a valid service account p12 key file.
    service_account_email: The service account email address.

  Returns:
    A service that is connected to the specified API.
  """

  credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_p12_keyfile(
    service_account_email, key_file_location, scopes=scope)

  http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())

  # Build the service object.
  service = build(api_name, api_version, http=http)

  return service


def get_first_profile_id(service):
  # Use the Analytics service object to get the first profile id.

  # Get a list of all Google Analytics accounts for this user
  accounts = service.management().accounts().list().execute()

  if accounts.get('items'):
    # Get the first Google Analytics account.
    account = accounts.get('items')[0].get('id')

    # Get a list of all the properties for the first account.
    properties = service.management().webproperties().list(
        accountId=account).execute()

    if properties.get('items'):
      # Get the first property id.
      property = properties.get('items')[0].get('id')

      # Get a list of all views (profiles) for the first property.
      profiles = service.management().profiles().list(
          accountId=account,
          webPropertyId=property).execute()

      if profiles.get('items'):
        # return the first view (profile) id.
        return profiles.get('items')[0].get('id')

  return None


def get_results(service, profile_id):
  # Use the Analytics Service Object to query the Core Reporting API
  # for the number of sessions within the past seven days.
  return service.data().ga().get(
      ids='ga:' + profile_id,
      start_date='7daysAgo',
      end_date='today',
      metrics='ga:sessions').execute()


def print_results(results):
  # Print data nicely for the user.
  if results:
    print 'View (Profile): %s' % results.get('profileInfo').get('profileName')
    print 'Total Sessions: %s' % results.get('rows')[0][0]

  else:
    print 'No results found'


def main():
  # Define the auth scopes to request.
  scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']

  # Use the developer console and replace the values with your
  # service account email and relative location of your key file.
  service_account_email = '<Replace with your service account email address.>'
  key_file_location = '<Replace with /path/to/generated/client_secrets.p12>'

  # Authenticate and construct service.
  service = get_service('analytics', 'v3', scope, key_file_location,
    service_account_email)
  profile = get_first_profile_id(service)
  print_results(get_results(service, profile))


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment out (or remove) the following line:

```
profile = get_first_profile_id(service)
```

In the next line enter the id of the profile you want to query manually as the second parameter

```
  print_results(get_results(service, '123456789'))
```

To get the profile id you can either visit the [query explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/), a nice google tool that allows to ad hoc queries to you authenticated accounts (i.e. you need to be logged in with the Google Account that has access to analytics). You can get the profile id from the "ids" field:

[image]

Or got to your analytics account, and in the reports look at the url. It will look like

```
https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/?authuser=0#report/defaultid/a1111110w65439246p123456789/
```

The profile id is at the end of the url (after the "p" character).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this post](http://www.ryanpraski.com/python-google-analytics-api-unsampled-data-multiple-profiles/) it has code that adapts the Google Analytics Python sample code and you can add multiple profile ids.

```
profile_ids = profile_ids = {'My Profile 1':  '1234567',
                             'My Profile 2':  '1234568',
                             'My Profile 3':  '1234569',
                             'My Profile 4':  '1234561'}

# Uncomment this line & replace with 'profile name': 'id' to query a single profile
# Delete or comment out this line to loop over multiple profiles.

## profile_ids = {'ryanpraski':  '1234567'}
```

-Ryan